# Solve right triangle given two points.

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve a right triangle given the coordinated of two points. This diagram explains the triangle better

[image: diagram]

We know the coordinates of point *A* and point *C*, we also know that the angle of *b* is 90 degrees. I would like to be able to find all the angles and side lengths. I know we can find the length of the hypotenuse using the distance formula the two known points however I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: The diagram makes it appear that the $y-$coordinate of B is the same as that of C, and that the $x-$coordinate of B is the same as that of A.  I don't know if that's what's intended, though.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not enough information to find it. If you draw a circle with diameter $AC$, $B$ could be anywhere on this circle. If we choose it properly, we can have the angles at $A$ and $C$ could be any two angles that sum up to 90 degrees.

Comment: My end goal is to find out how far to the left or right point C is from A, and how far in front or behind it is. Is there a different way that I should be trying to solve this?

Comment: @Bernard "My end goal is to find out how far to the left or right point C is from A" So there does $B$ come into the picture? You cave the coordinates for $A$ and $C$.

Comment: I need a way to find the distance for any given coordiantes (lon,lat), and with any possible heading of the user.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ can be any point on the circle with diameter $AC$. Therefore neither angles nor side lengths can be determined. In other words the problem has a solution for any $0<\alpha<\frac\pi2$, and for any $0<a<b$.

Answer (score 0):

A corollary of Euclidian geometry says:

All inscribed angles in a semicircunference are right angles.

Like in this [gif](https://www.petervis.com/mathematics/Triangle_Inscribed_in_a_Semicircle/Triangle_Inscribed_in_a_Semicircle/Triangle_Inscribed_in_a_Semicircle_Animated_Diagram.gif)

So you have infinite answers to your question